# 404 is working instead of custom blog template

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, blogs

I am developing an Wordpress template right now. I have a static index page. For my blog posts, I am using a custom template named `Blog`. But when I create a page under this `Blog` template and try to view the page; it doesn't show the blog page rather it shows `404.php`

I am using these files:

```
index.php //static index page
blog.php //blog page under Blog template
404.php
```

This is my site http://ratcat.bugs3.com/samata/
And this is the blog page which isn't not working http://ratcat.bugs3.com/samata/blog-6

For more help, here is my blog.php main code segment:

```
            <div class="single_post">
                <?php
                // The Query
                $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                query_posts("paged=$page");
                // The Loop
                if(have_posts()) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left_date">

                                <h1><?php the_time('d') ?></h1>
                                <p><?php the_time('M') ?></p>
                                <span class="year"><p><?php the_time('Y') ?></p></span>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                            <div class="author_tag">
                                <span class="author">By: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                                <span class="tag"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image', array('class' => 'post-thumb')); ?></a>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <div class="read_comment">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Full post"><span class="read">Read more</span></a>
                                    <span class="comment"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="gap"></div>
                <?php
                    endwhile; ?>
                    <table class="nav_post">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Previous posts') ); ?></div></td>
                            <td><div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>') ); ?></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    // Reset Query
                    wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: ok first check if it is cause my permalink structure change ur permalink to default and see any thing happens or not

Comment: can you paste your permalink setting and also check if rewrite module is enable .

Comment: Nothing happens. Same 404 problem. One thing, I have also a custom template named Personal Journey, when I create a page under it. The page works fine. @anstrangel0ver

Comment: check the down answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try some thing like put a template code on your blog.php like paste code

```
<?php
/*
 * Template name: blog Template
 */
?>
```

and after that in your admin where your blog page edit your template you can see blog template in dropdown while editing the blog page. hope this will work for you.

Comment: I used the custom template name as "Blog" :(, now it's working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this I think your issue is that you should have called the template page-blog.php to have it automatically used as the template for a page with the name (and presumably the slug?) of 'Blog'.

See the codex here;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

> The WordPress Template Hierarchy also recognizes specific Pages or
>   Posts automatically without the need to assign them to a specific Page
>   template file. If the Page with ID or slug in the template file name
>   is created by the user, the appropriate Page template file is
>   automatically used.
>
> page-{id}.php
>
> page-{slug}.php

Comment: Yes, I used the custom template name as "Blog" :(, now it's working fine. Thanks a lot.